# What to do in order to use SQL in docker container deployed in cloud?

Tags: python, sqlite, docker, openstack

Right now, I have a simple web server in Python, pacakaged in a docker container, Linux based. That container is deployed in a private openstack cloud and a volume is attached to the container, mounted.

The web server is saving data in a json file on the volume. However, I would like to replace that saving mechanism by a SQL database (postgrest? sqlite?).

I don't have experience with database management (I know queries though). How do I install SQL in that container? Does it need to be on the volume or there is a way to install to software in the container and use the volume only for the actual data?

Comment: One doesn't install SQL, one installs a specific database.  But in a Dockerised world, you just spin up a separate database container.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about Openstack and answer this by thinking it will be similar to a dedicated Linux server. If that assumption should be wrong then there is probably a much better answer out there.

I suggest you use a separate container for the DB, preferably based on a well-known public image. Personally I have experience with mysql fork [mariadb](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/).

Use [a docker-compose.yml file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) to link these containers together by adding an entry, like so:

```
your_existing_container:
  image: your_image
  ports:
    - 80:80
  links:
    - db
  volumes_from:
    - your_existing_volume

db:
  image: mariadb:10.1
  volumes_from:
    - dbdata
  expose:
    - 3306
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=nameme
    - MYSQL_USER=callme
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=changeme

dbdata:
  image: tianon/true
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
```

Once you have this in place (and changed the passwords etc. for the db), navigate to the directory where the `docker-compose.yml` file is located and run `docker-compose up -d your_existing_container` (rename that of course). Compose will run your image as well as all others it depends on (like your db container).